# Angular best practice: for reusability, make new CSS class or new component?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

I have this div and set of CSS properties (the properties themselves are unimportant, they're just examples) that are core to my app, and that I'll be reusing a lot throughout multiple pages and other components.

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%">
//here there will be some inner html that will vary based on the context it's being used in
</div>
```

Given that this is such simple html and that no data/event binding will interact with this `div`, what (and why) is the best pratice here:

- new CSS class,
- new angular component containing `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside,
- something else?

Comment: Is not very clear what you want to do, but probably a combination of both practices, you should do a css to contain your style, but i'm not sure if you want to put the ng-content inside that div.

Comment: @DiegoBascans I've made some edits, hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could see, I gathered that the best solution is to simply make a CSS class, like so:

```css
div.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Reasons:

- [K.I.S.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)
- doesn't introduce additional html nesting, which can cause friction with things like flexbox and therefore is less maintanable

In my view, angular components should only be created if either of the following criteria is met:

- their template is consists of multiple html elements (in the example in the question there is only one)
- they utilize custom logic, either in TypeScript or angular template syntax, e.g. `ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

Based in your example probably you will need a combination of both practices.

```
<div class="myBaseStyle">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Where your css will look like this.

```
.myBaseStyle {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100%
}
```

Since you want to reuse that div in several places, is a very good practice to create a component, since if you need to edit something in that particular DIV, you just to update it in one place and not in every location. What if in the future you need to add more html to that DIV, you will have to refacor your whole solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why? For example, I could get away with not making a new component, and just using `div`s with the `myBaseStyle ` class wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `style.css` under the `src folder` of the angular app, Make a global style like this:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div


.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100%;

   &.child-element { //like this you can add styles to chuld elements.
     ...
   }
}
```

In this way just copy and paste your HTML and styles will automatically be applied from style.css on the root.

If you want to edit the styles somewhere in the specific component then, in either case, you can `@extend` your styles from the `style.css` file into the `x.compnent.css` you will get the previous styles in `x.compnent.css` you can make further changes in your way.

Example to `@extend` styles:

```
@extend .flex-container;
  display: block;
```